# ListView SELECT query not returning anything

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am building a library management software and im trying to search books by name. However when I try to use what Ive implemented nothing gets returned.

This is the code behind used to retrieve data from the db.

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LibraryContext"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                string bookTitle = Request.QueryString["BookTitle"];
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", bookTitle); 
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Title LIKE '%@Title%'";
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", bookTitle); 
                cmd.Connection = con;

                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    lvCustomers.DataSource = dt;
                    lvCustomers.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
```

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not put quotes around your parameter

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Title LIKE %@Title%";
```

Quotes aroud the parameters tranform everything inside them to a literal string and of course I suppose that you don't have any book whose title is literally "%@Title%"

also I prefer to use a

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Title LIKE @Title";       
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "%" + bookTitle + "%");
```

AddWithValue is a shortcut with numerous drawback that you need to aware of before trying to use it: [Can we stop to use AddWithValue already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: However now the compiler complains about `incorrect syntax near @Title`

Comment: using the %@Title% or the second approach?

Comment: Actually it happens in both cases.

Comment: Oh my bad I forgot to delete the `%` in the SQL statement. It works perfectly now.